# Nginx Embedded Variables - How do you get the domain name used in a request?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, https, http, openssl

When using multiple domain names for one server, how do you get the domain name currently being used in a request? I'm using the embedded variables for Nginx in it's configuration file.

I've set up OpenSSL and have a redirect that works fine for my first domain since, as you can see, I'm explicitly redirecting to it at the bottom of my config file. So an HTTP request on any of the other domains redirects to that first one for a secure connection. Is there an embedded variable I can use, similar to `$request_uri`, for example, but just returns the given domain name used by the client?

Here's the server block where I'm running the redirect.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com example1.com example2.com example3.com;
        location / {
                return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
        }
}
```

And the rest of my config: https://pastebin.com/HgnZ0aBe

Comment: Here is a link that contains all the variables used in the nginx conf files http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html

Comment: And this would be the link to the variable usage of what you are looking for http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Domain name that used in request is basically a host request header. In nginx, variable for host header is $host. So if you want to redirect based on domain name/host you should change the configuration to :

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

Hope this help . Thanks

Comment: But does this not include the subdomain? What if you need the domain without the subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

From `server_name` [`variable documentation`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_name), you can try with "named capture groups". This handles subdomains (but not the subdomain-less corner cases...):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    # Version 1: <subdomain> stops capturing at the first dot
    server_name ~ ^(?<subdomain>[^.]+)?\.(?<domain>.+)$;
    # Version 2: <subdomain> captures up to the last dot before <domain>
    # server_name ~ ^(?<subdomain>.+)?\.(?<domain>[^.]+?\.[^.]+)$;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$domain$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ...
    # common <domain>-specific stuff, e.g.
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/fullchain.pem;
    ...

    # do something by <subdomain>, e.g. for a multisite installation
    location ^~ /sites {
        alias /var/www/sites/$domain/$subdomain/;
        ...
    }
}
```

See also [this blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/regular-expression-tester-nginx/).

### Testing with Perl.

```bash
$ dlist="
example.com
foo.example1.com
bar.example2.com
foo.bar.example.com
"
```

#### Version 1

(Cannot handle first case.)

```bash
$ echo "$dlist" | perl -wne 'chomp; /^(?<subdomain>[^.]+)?\.(?<domain>.+)$/ && print "subdomain: $+{subdomain}, domain: $+{domain}\n"'
subdomain: example, domain: com
subdomain: foo, domain: example1.com
subdomain: bar, domain: example2.com
subdomain: foo, domain: bar.example.com
```

#### Version 2

(Does not match the first case.)

```bash
$ echo "$dlist" | perl -wne 'chomp; /^(?<subdomain>.+)?\.(?<domain>[^.]+?\.[^.]+)$/ && print "subdomain: $+{subdomain}, domain: $+{domain}\n"'
subdomain: foo, domain: example1.com
subdomain: bar, domain: example2.com
subdomain: foo.bar, domain: example.com
```